# Register for COM Interop Always Runs in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: vb6, visual-studio-2012, com-interop

I have a solution with several projects that have `Register for COM Interop` checked.

I have a Visual Basic 6 project that references the resulting TLBs.  One issue with VB6 is when it references a dll/tlb, it puts a lock on that file.

Using Visual Studio 2010, unless I'm doing a rebuild or have made a change to one of these interop projects, I can build/run the solution (with the VB6 project open) without it barking that one or more of the assemblies is locked.

However, using Visual Studio 2012, even on a simple build where nothing has changed, apparently it always does the regasm, which makes it impossible for me to debug my VB6 project.

Is this new *feature* of Visual Studio of running regasm on build something that I can turn off?

**EDIT:** Allow me to simplify:

- Using Visual Studio 2010, I hit `Build-->Build Solution` and check the output for one of my assemblies that is marked as `Register for COM Interop` and the file has not changed.
- Using Visual Studio 2012, I do `Build-->Build Solution` and check the same assembly, it has been updated, and does so every time I hit `Build Solution`.

I want the behavior in Visual Studio 2012 to work the same as it did in 2010.

**EDIT (again):**
I posted this to [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/767965/register-for-com-interop-always-runs-in-visual-studio-2012). If someone answers it there or posts a workaround, I'll urge them to also post the answer here.

Comment: I find this surprising as VB6 always keeps a lock on the file. I cannot recompile my VS2010 projects if I have a VB6 app open that is referencing the 2010 project

Comment: @MattWilko: As I said, in VS2010 I can't keep VB6 open if I'm **rebuilding**, but if it's just **build**, it works.

Comment: Have you tried reporting this as a bug to Microsoft at their [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com) site?

Comment: @HolisticDeveloper: Thanks.  I think that's where I'm going to have to take this.

Comment: Maybe you could make a seperate build target (like DEBUG) in which the interop assemblies are not build?

Answer (score 0):

I've always encountered problems like this when running VB6 and VS20XX, but I always did a rebuild. My suggestion is to stop using VB6 for testing purposes. I found it was far easier to simply create a testing project and do all of my testing in .NET on my .NET code. This should only require a small amount of set up, but it is well worth it in my opinion.

I know this isn't an answer to your specific question, but it offers an alternative. As far as the problem you are describing, I can't duplicate a change in behavior. I start off with only VS201X open, full solution rebuild, open VB6 and add a reference to an exposed COM DLL. I didn't notice anything unexpected.

1. Build works fine as long as I haven't changed anything in the COM DLL
2. Build fails if I changed the COM DLL's code as the file is locked
3. Rebuild fails as the file is locked

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, not using VB6 for debugging is not an issue as there are interdependencies between the C# code and the VB6 code--not necessarily circular references, but more eliptical. I updated my question to (hopefully) clarify what the root problem/question is.